# Magento - Store Views and multiple currencies - Checkout using base currency always

Tags: php, magento, paypal, currency

I have a magento website

- We have a store
- In a store we have multiple store views (US, EU and UK)
- Each store view has it's own currency, etc.
- The base currency is GBP at the default config (main)

My problem is that the display currencies work well. Each store view has it's own individual price (no automatic conversion). Everything seems to be working and in order. However, on the final payment emails and actual connection with payment providers (PayPal/Sage). The base currency is always used. Although the display appears in the currency for each store view.

My question is why are the store view currencies not used with PayPal, emails, etc. Although the amounts, display currency, etc work fine?

Comment: what version are you using? Magento version

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out that Base Currency can be set on each Store View. However, this option was not presented on the admin side. I had to change the system.xml

app/code/core/Mage/Directory/etc/system.xml

```
<label>Base Currency</label>
```

I have to set the appropriate to change from 0 to 1

```
<show_in_store>1</show_in_store>
```

Once this was done, I could see Base Currency under "Currency Options" even within a store view. This now works well and everything seems to be working fine.

No PHP code changes or any additional plugins required.

Answer (score 0):

When I had run into this issue with a rather large Magento store, this quick fix worked pretty well for me: [Magento knowledge-base paypal base currency tweak](http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/3_-_store_setup_and_management/payment/tweak_paypal_standard_for_non-supported_base_currency)

Just note that, that fix probably won't work out of the box but it'll take some tweaking

Comment: Are you sure that is required? Felt like something that has to be in Magento settings of some sort.

Comment: There's a lot of quirks in Magento.. it's ridiculous that they can't handle international currencies properly out of the box but this was the only way I could find to solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Here it is some solutions.
You might custom some codes
If you are using Paypal Express, 
\app\code\core\Mage\Paypal\Model\Express.php

```
protected function _placeOrder(Mage_Sales_Model_Order_Payment $payment, $amount)
{
    $order = $payment->getOrder();

    // prepare api call
    $token = $payment->getAdditionalInformation(Mage_Paypal_Model_Express_Checkout::PAYMENT_INFO_TRANSPORT_TOKEN);
    $api = $this->_pro->getApi()
        ->setToken($token)
        ->setPayerId($payment->
            getAdditionalInformation(Mage_Paypal_Model_Express_Checkout::PAYMENT_INFO_TRANSPORT_PAYER_ID))
        ->setAmount($amount)
        ->setPaymentAction($this->_pro->getConfig()->paymentAction)
        ->setNotifyUrl(Mage::getUrl('paypal/ipn/'))
        ->setInvNum($order->getIncrementId())
        **->setCurrencyCode($order->getOrderCurrencyCode())** // should be used getOrderCurrencyCode();
        ->setPaypalCart(Mage::getModel('paypal/cart', array($order)))
        ->setIsLineItemsEnabled($this->_pro->getConfig()->lineItemsEnabled)
    ;
    if ($order->getIsVirtual()) {
        $api->setAddress($order->getBillingAddress())->setSuppressShipping(true);
    } else {
        $api->setAddress($order->getShippingAddress());
        $api->setBillingAddress($order->getBillingAddress());
    }

    // call api and get details from it
    $api->callDoExpressCheckoutPayment();

    $this->_importToPayment($api, $payment);
    return $this;
}
```

\app\code\core\Mage\Paypal\Model\Standard.php

```
public function getStandardCheckoutFormFields()
{
    $orderIncrementId = $this->getCheckout()->getLastRealOrderId();
    $order = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->loadByIncrementId($orderIncrementId);
    /* @var $api Mage_Paypal_Model_Api_Standard */
    $api = Mage::getModel('paypal/api_standard')->setConfigObject($this->getConfig());
    $api->setOrderId($orderIncrementId)
        **->setCurrencyCode($order->getOrderCurrencyCode())** // should be used getOrderCurrencyCode();
        //->setPaymentAction()
        ->setOrder($order)
        ->setNotifyUrl(Mage::getUrl('paypal/ipn/'))
        ->setReturnUrl(Mage::getUrl('paypal/standard/success'))
        ->setCancelUrl(Mage::getUrl('paypal/standard/cancel'));

    // export address
    $isOrderVirtual = $order->getIsVirtual();
    $address = $isOrderVirtual ? $order->getBillingAddress() : $order->getShippingAddress();
    if ($isOrderVirtual) {
        $api->setNoShipping(true);
    } elseif ($address->validate()) {
        $api->setAddress($address);
    }

    // add cart totals and line items
    $api->setPaypalCart(Mage::getModel('paypal/cart', array($order)))
        ->setIsLineItemsEnabled($this->_config->lineItemsEnabled)
    ;
    $api->setCartSummary($this->_getAggregatedCartSummary());
    $api->setLocale($api->getLocaleCode());
    $result = $api->getStandardCheckoutRequest();
    return $result;
}
```